# directline v3 gives error 400

Tags: python, python-requests, botframework, direct-line-botframework

In the Step **Sending an Activity to the bot** As per the documentation Here,

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/#navtitle

I should pass this as the body content of the post request

```
{
  "type": "message",
  "from": {
    "id": "user1"
  },
  "text": "hello"
}
```

I am using the following parameters to make POST request in python, but its not working.

```
msg = {"type": "message","channelId": "directline","conversation":{"id": str(convId)},"from":{"id": "test_user1"},"text": "hello"}
header = {"Authorization":"Bearer q1-Tr4sRrAI.cwA.BmE.n7xMxGl-QLoT7qvJ-tNIcwAd69V-KOn5see6ki5tmOM", "Content-Type":"application/json", "Content-Length": "512"}
send2 = "https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/"+str(convId)+"/activities"
rsa1 = requests.post(send2,data=msg, headers=header)
```

This gives me this error:

```
{
  "error": {
  "code": "MissingProperty",
  "message": "Invalid or missing activities in HTTP body"
   }
}
```

Before this step everything is working fine.

Edit 1: Even i added content-length as updated in the code, it gives the same error

Edit 2: If i changed the msg to json.dumps(msg)

```
rsa1 = requests.post(send2,data=json.dumps(msg), headers=header)
```

I get response:

```
{u'error': {u'message': u'Failed to send activity: bot returned an error', u'code': u'ServiceError'}}
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ServiceError",
    "message": "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error"
  }
}
```

The directline API is only not working, on skype client everything is working fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MissingProperty error in Microsoft Bot Framework Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727907/missingproperty-error-in-microsoft-bot-framework-request)

Comment: No, i have added the Content-Length but it also doesnt work.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code that you've posted, your request body looks like this:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "channelId": "directline",
    "conversation": {
        "id": str(convId)
    },
    "from": {
        "id": "test_user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
}
```

I'd suspect that your error is caused by the fact that the conversation ID value that you're including in the request body is not surrounded with double quotes in the JSON that's sent over the wire.

For simplicity (and to eliminate the error you're receiving), I'd suggest that you try omitting the **channelId** property and the **conversation** property from the request body, as I don't believe that either of these properties are necessary (i.e., you are issuing the request to the Direct Line URI, so the Bot Framework knows that Direct Line is the channel, and the conversation ID is already being specified in the request URI). In other words, try this as your request body:

```
{
    "type": "message",
    "from": {
        "id": "test_user1"
    },
    "text": "hello"
}
```

Comment: I tried all the stuff, first i took the value of activity from the example given in their docs itself. None worked

Answer (score 0):

When passing a dictionary to `data` it gets urlencoded automatically, so the api returns an error as it expects json data.

You can either use the `json` lib, or preferably pass your dictionary to the `json` parameter.
 Using `json.dumps` :

```
rsa1 = requests.post(send2, data=json.dumps(msg), headers=header)
```

Using `requests` only :

```
rsa1 = requests.post(send2, json=msg, headers=header)
```

Also you don't have to add "Content-Length" in `header` and if you use the second example you don't have to add "Content-Type" either.

Comment: I tried all of these, none of them worked. I am stuck in this problem for a month now. I have clicked on every relevant link on almost every search engine :P Still no fix., But yes, the error becomes 502 when i do the way you suggested, 

    {u'error': {u'message': u'Failed to send activity: bot returned an error', u'code': u'ServiceError'}} rsa1
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "ServiceError",
        "message": "Failed to send activity: bot returned an error"
      }
    }

Comment: This problem is coming only in directline API, for other Rest API it is working fine